# Trying to use javascript to add a new form row and insert into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

The add new row works ( well it adds a new row ) but when i try and submit the data to the database its coming back with array. I tried it without putting the [] at the end of the name tags in the form but all it submited then was the first row.

Sorry to ask a dumb question but ive been racking my brains on how to get this to work.

Heres my code:

```
<?php
    if($user->data()->username = $res->username) {
        if(isset($_POST['results'])) {
            $submitres = DB::getInstance()->insert('results', array(
                'torneyid'      => Input::get('torneyid'),
                'buyin'         => Input::get('buyin'),
                'torneydesc'    => Input::get('description'),
                'finish'        => Input::get('finish'),
                'profit_loss'   => Input::get('profit'),
                'eventid'       => $res->id
                    ));
        }
        echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Torney ID</th>
                <th class="hidden-sm">Torney Description</th>
                <th>Buy-In</th>
                <th>Finish Pos</th>
                <th>Profit/Loss</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="torneyid[]" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td class="hidden-sm"><input name="description[]" type="text" value="" class="fm-control" /></td>
                <td><input name="buyin[]" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input name="finish[]" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input name="profit[]" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="results" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Results</button>
    <a id="add"><button class="btn btn-primary">Add Row</button></a>
        </form>';
    }
```

?>

My java script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").click(function() {
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for any help!

FIXED - Will add how i done it just in case it helps anyone else in the fuiture:

Changed the code from if(isset) to:

```
if(isset($_POST['results'])) {
    for ( $row = 0; $row < count( $_POST["torneyid"] ); ++$row ) {
        $tid = $_POST["torneyid"][$row];
        $desc = $_POST["description"][$row];
        $buy = $_POST['buyin'][$row];
        $fin = $_POST['finish'][$row];
        $prof = $_POST['profit'][$row];

    $submitres = DB::getInstance()->insert('results', array(
        'torneyid'      => $tid,
        'buyin'         => $desc,
        'torneydesc'    => $buy,
        'finish'        => $fin,
        'profit_loss'   => $prof,
        'eventid'       => $res->id

        ));
}
```

Comment: loop over array of `torneyid` and use index to create insert for each row

Comment: @charlietfl could you give me an example? or somewhere i can see what you mean? Sorry im a tad thick you see haha